# What is the best way to score it?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem to solve: I have a list of regions such as:

- Brazil [Data collected since 1900]
- USA [Data collected since 2000]
- Australia [Data collected since 2010]
- Russia [Data collected since 2019]

And I have a list of incidents that happened there (Only example)

```
[12/01/2018] Brazil: Flood
[08/02/2019] USA: Tornado
[08/02/2016] Australia: Tornado
[01/01/2014] Australia: Landslide
[01/03/2010] USA: Tornado
```

What is the best way to give a score to the most hazardous location, considering number of events and time.

For instance:

Incidents that happened next to today must have lower score.
If more than an incident occurred in the region, it must have a lower score.

**Score:**

Must be between 0 and 1000.

0: Most hazardous place (More chance of an incident or an incident has just occurred)

1000: Most safe place (no incidents in a long period)

**What is the best way to create a score? How should we deal with new places? How may we consider the time when a place was registered and the number of  incidents that it has?**

Comment: The situation is only an exemple. The parameters are only for a study case.

Comment: This might be better asked at the stats stackexchange.